# How can I find a Control inside WizardStep?

Tags: c#, asp.net, findcontrol

I'm using the CreateWizardStep for create user to my site... I added new step and inside the step a put a CheckBoxList, but I'm trying to search this control but it return null reference error, below a code snip:

ASPX

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="RegisterUserWithRoles" runat="server" ContinueDestinationPageUrl="~/Default.aspx" LoginCreatedUser="False" OnActiveStepChanged="RegisterUserWithRoles_ActiveStepChanged" ActiveStepIndex="1">
    <WizardSteps>
        <asp:CreateUserWizardStep runat="server" />
        <asp:WizardStep ID="SpecifyRolesStep" runat="server" AllowReturn="False" StepType="Step" Title="Specify Roles">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="RoleList" runat="server" />
        </asp:WizardStep>
        <asp:CompleteWizardStep runat="server" />
    </WizardSteps>
</asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

C#

```
// Reference the SpecifyRolesStep WizardStep .
WizardStep SpecifyRolesStep = RegisterUserWithRoles.FindControl("SpecifyRolesStep") as WizardStep;

// Reference the RoleList CheckBoxList 
CheckBoxList RoleList = SpecifyRolesStep.FindControl("RoleList") as CheckBoxList;

// Bind the set of roles to RoleList 
RoleList.DataSource = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetAllRoles();
RoleList.DataBind();
```

How can I find this CheckBoxList  Control inside the StepWizard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be null because the `as` keyword is trying and failing to cast a checkbox as a checkboxlist.

Try changing the RoleList to `<asp:CheckBoxList ID="RoleList" runat="server"> </asp:CheckBoxList>`

Comment: I lot of thanks! I beleived that I could convert checkbox to checkboxlist... but now I found that it not possible do it the cast...

Answer (score 0):

You have to get to the wizard step first before you can access the control

```
if (Wizard1.ActiveStep.Title == "Specify Roles")
        {
            CheckBox RoleList = RegisterUserWithRoles.ActiveStep.FindControl("RoleList") as CheckBox;

        }
```

I found this here:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1265377.aspx/1